# Multi Domain Corporate Branding

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

Looking into the possibility of have two companies on the same office 365 admin console but have two sets of corporate branding so that the companies get the correct logos.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Kind regards
Tom

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Active Directory, Branding Customization is a Configuration of a **Directory**, not a specific **Domain**. You can go to [Classic Portal](http://Https://manage.windowsazure.com)  - Active Directory - *Click Your Directory* - **Configure** - **Customize Branding**.

So for all domains within a single directory, accounts will get the same company branding in Azure service sign-in page or Access Panel page https://myapps.microsoft.com.

So if you want to get different branding, you need to use different directories. Customize branding on Microsoft document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding):